# C, Eliminating loop when calling fread?

Tags: c, file, memory, fopen, fread

In C I wrote this code:

```
char tmp[strlen(argv[1]) + 1];
for (int j = 0; j < strlen(argv[1]) + 1; ++j) {
    fread(&tmp[j], 1, 1, file);
}
```

I prefer to eliminate the for loop to make the code shorter so is it equal to this (option A):

```
char tmp[strlen(argv[1]) + 1];
fread(&tmp, 1, strlen(argv[1]) + 1, file);
```

and this (option B):

```
char tmp[strlen(argv[1]) + 1];
fread(&tmp, strlen(argv[1]) + 1, 1 ,file);
```

From what I read on `fread` the answer is yes for both but want to understand what's preferable A or B?

Comment: None of them are preferable. You should check the return value of `fread()` to check if it succeeded to read things. If you will do the check, option A may be better because you can know the actual number of bytes read from the return value in that case.

Comment: But all are correct?

Comment: I don't think so because later code won't be able to know if the contents of `tmp` is valid or uninitialized without checking the return value of `fread()`.

Comment: From Syntax, yes, they are correct. For logic its what you defined. If you would read a file that does not contain a terminating `\0` or the contents do not fit into your array, you end up with an unterminated cstring and you have no idea how much data really is stored in your array. So your code would not be considered robust. And you have no idea what kind of data you got. So at the very least, you should store the return value of `fread` to know what kind of data you are dealing with.

Comment: What is stored in `argv[1]`? Is that the filename of the input file? If that is the case, please note that `strlen(argv[1])` will not give you the length of the file, it will only give you the length of the filename. In order to find the length of the file, you must actually read the file until you encounter `EOF`, or if the file is opened in binary mode, you can also `fseek` to the end of the file and then use `ftell`. You can probably also use a platform-specific function to tell you the length of a file.

Comment: `argv[1]` is a string. The length is arbitrary based on the number of characters. If you want to read some specific number of characters from a binary file, convert the string representation of a number to a number, e.g. `./myprogram 512`, then to read `512` bytes from the file, convert `argv[1]` to a numeric value, e.g. `strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the options is preferrable in my opinion and without knowing what you want to achieve, there is no answer to that.

From Syntax, your code would compile and is correct. From the logic point of view its unusable.

You do not know in your code how much data has been actually read, so you cannot work with the data stored in tmp. If your file contents are larger than your array or the file does not contain a null-terminator (which it most likely does not if its a textfile) you have no indicator of any kind how much chars got read into your array.

At the **very least** you should store the return value of `fread` to know how much data has been actually read and how much data is valid in your array. Another way would be to initialize your array completly with zero bytes (either by `= {};` or by `memset`) to make sure after valid data a nullterminator is found or your array is completly full, so you can terminate when reading from the array.

Keep some things in mind:

1. Loops are not evil nor clutter code or slow down execution in such an extend that you can justify not using them when reading **user input** (which a file is imho)
2. You are dealing with user input, so expect unexpected data and unexpected sizes. Your code should deal with that in order to write robust and error-tolerant code.
3. Read errors can occur. So if you want to read the full file, be prepared for that. For example reading will be terminated if your program gets interrupted by a signal (at least on linux). So you might need multiple attempts so read your entire file. Signals happen and you cannot guarantee that they will not. E.g. if you forked another process and the other process dies, it will trigger `SIGCHILD`. Just as an example.
4. You use the `strlen` of `argv[1]` as your array length. That does not tell you if the contents of `file` will fit into that. So your should clarify your question on what your program actually should do. Also if you think that `file` will fit in `tmp` based on the length or `argv[1]`, its still a file you read which might contain unexpected stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: none of the options is correct (But maybe the option B makes some sense)

Explanation:
The first thing you have to take a look at is the fread documentation to know what each parameter is used for:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fread?view=msvc-160

So the second parameter is the item size in bytes and the third parameter is the maximum number of items to be read.

That means in the second parameter you should pass the total length of the content of file variable that you want to read. (Your code maybe makes some sense if strlen(argv[1])+1 contains that length, but it is not a good practice to do that).

As a recomendation: do not try to make your code have few lines compromising bug control, readability, or other issues and do not think that the user (argv) will use your program well.